# bootstrap 3 make div height 50% of the parent div

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I need to set two **div** elements disposed vertically within a **div** parent, and inside each div there should be an image. All image should be responsive and fit the div height, so the image of **div1** should be larger

```
 _____________
|div1 | div2  |
|     |-------
|_____|_div3__|
```

I put a code example here, but it doesn't work.
How can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/fstarred/tonq8wdq/

Comment: Bootstrap has an "equal height" option as I recall...you should start there,

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning! You can [edit] your question to include the needed informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well your requirements can be satisfied using the right width of bootstrap grids as follows -

see this [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ManojSalvi/tonq8wdq/3/)

Code -

```
<div class="row col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
    <div class="panel panel-info"> 
        <div class="panel-heading"> 
            <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#">title</a></h3> 
        </div> 
        <div class="panel-body">                            
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="main" src="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/5a/2e/e9/5a2ee9b3-8f0e-4f8b-4043-dd3e3ea29766/icon128-2x.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>          
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <div class="row col-md-12">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" alt="col1" src="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/5a/2e/e9/5a2ee9b3-8f0e-4f8b-4043-dd3e3ea29766/icon128-2x.png" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row col-md-12">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" alt="col2" src="http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/5a/2e/e9/5a2ee9b3-8f0e-4f8b-4043-dd3e3ea29766/icon128-2x.png" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>                                                  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works like a charm!! thank you !!!

Comment: Happy to help.. :) , you can accept my answer if it works for you...